# Rails - Images API for quick Resizing? Something like Google App Engine's Images Python API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

Google's app engine has this speedy image resizing api which appears to perform significantly faster than the rails paperclip resizing alternative.

Anyone know of any rails/heroku friend image resizing api's that could work with paperclip to be a faster resizing solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do images on heroku, you're usually storing them up on S3.

You can upload the [file directly to S3](http://docs.heroku.com/s3#direct-upload), then use [delayed](http://docs.heroku.com/delayed-job) [job](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/11/19/delayed-gratification-with-rails/) to process the file in the background. Your users will see a zippier/faster processing time.

Comment: Also this SOW question has good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054108/uploading-to-s3-on-heroku-with-paperclip-delayed-job-question

Comment: Thanks Jesse I like that idea but never really understood it given. A user goes to upload photos. When the photos are done you show the user the photos. But if I use delayed_job, I can't do that use case?

Comment: @AnApprentice: depends exactly what you're doing. If you need need need to show the resulting thumbnails immediately, that's one thing. If it'd be okay to show "thumbnail pending" for a little while in its place (and it might even be done by the time the user gets to the next page, anyway), then that's that.

Comment: @AnApprentice: Matchu is exactly correct... As for your question, you would upload the file, then you'd send an AJAX call to your application, telling it the model_id and the S3 path to use. Then kickoff a delayed job.

Answer (score 3):

We've used Transloadit and it works well:

http://transloadit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip itself doesn't include image-resizing code; it simply plugs into tools like ImageMagick and MiniMagick. Have you tried some of these other engines?

Comment: good point, Im using ImageMagick now then. What other engines do you suggest?

Comment: @AnApprentice: I moved to MiniMagick after having issues with RMagick (gem for ImageMagick) taking up too much memory on bulk jobs. Consider giving that a go.